# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Client-Validation with money field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I did followed this blog **[here](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2011/01/28/aspnet-mvc-3-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-unobtrusive-javascript.aspx)** and **[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx)**.

And i have the following problem.

One field in my form is currecy format, from brazil.
I'm using client-side validation. Everything works great expept one issue.

I have 2 validation:

```
[DisplayName("Taxa de adesão")]
[MoedaReal(ErrorMessage = "Taxa deve ser numérico")]        
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Taxa é obrigatório")]
public decimal ValorAdesao { get; set; }
```

The rule REQUIRED works ok, the MoedaReal rule works okay.
After these rules are passed ok, one final rule is triggered:

- ***The field Taxa de adesão must be a number***

I already tried to change the web.config in this line:

```
<globalization culture="pt-br" uiCulture="pt-br" />
```

My numbers format accepcted are these:

```
1,00
11,00
111,00
1.111,00
11.111,00
111.111,00
1.111.111,00
1.111.111.111.111,00
```

How can i "fool" .NET to accept this format? Because it expects DECIMAL format instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fool the default model binder. It simply tries to parse the request string value into a decimal using the culture specified in your web.config. So because you are also using client validation there might be a culture difference between the client and the server. For example the browser could be configured to use en-US and the server pt-BR and then you might have a problem. You could try this:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
```

This means that the culture used by the server will be dictated by the client. If this doesn't work you have a couple of other possibilities:

- Write a custom model binder
- Use string instead of decimal and then do the parsing manually

Comment: Using string solved all the problem. It didnt cross my mind! thanks